# Параметры url не попадают в $_GET

Tags: php

Когда для ссылок добавляю параметры после ? , эти параметры не появляются в $_GET.
Например ссылка

```
<a href="/blog?page=5">Ссылка</a>
```

При переходе по ней, $_GET['page'] пустой.
На локале(openserver) раньше всё работало. Перенёс на vps(nginx php7-fpm) и перестало работать

Comment: а на локалке на nginx тоже работало в опенсервере (т.к. там вариантов конфигурации много) ? И какие конфиги nginx сейчас, подозреваю дело имено в роутинге и конфигах nginx

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте какие значения есть в $_SERVER.
Проверьте в браузере код ответа 200 или какой либо редирект.
Содержание $_GET вы выводите на самом входе в скрипты или до этого уже что-то отрабатывает?
Проверьте не работает ли у вас какой то js скрипт, который перехватывает все клики и обрабатывает о своему.